# Can i programatically keypress via HID devices keyboard?

Tags: c#, selenium

i got a task to auto login a webpage.However the  textbox for the password is special handler using browser plugin to 
restrict non-human keyboard key in.So i do some research on this.I found and used a library in C# https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ 
to try key in the password text to the textbox unfortunately still cannot key in.
I want to ask is that anyway to simulator a HID Keyboard and key in to textbox?